# Mathematica-Converting a polynomial function into a list and extracting the terms from it

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a mathematica polynomial function which I would like to convert to a list of terms. i.e.
for a function

```
   v[a_,b_,c_]:=a^2+b^2+c^2
```

I can get the terms in the form of a list by using MonomialList i.e.

```
   vl[a_,b_,c_]:=MonomialList[v[a,b,c]]
```

which gives me:

```
   vl[a,b,c]={a^2,b^2,c^2};
```

Now I would like to make separate functions from each of these terms so that I get:

```
   vl[1,1,1]={1,1,1}
```

Instead of

```
   vl[1,1,1]=3
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
v[a_, b_, c_] := a^2 + b^2 + c^2
vl[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{x, y, z}, 
                         MonomialList[v[x, y, z]] /. {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}]
vl[1, 1, 1]
(*
 -> {1,1,1}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, just replacing the set delay symbol ':=' with a set symbol '=' works i.e.      vl[a_,b_,c_]=MonomialList[v[a,b,c]]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason not to pre-compute the list, like this:

```
v[a_, b_, c_] := a^2 + b^2 + c^2

Block[{a, b, c},
 vf[a_, b_, c_] = MonomialList[v[a, b, c]];
]
```

Testing:

```
vf[q, r, s]
vf[1, 1, 1]
```

> ```
> {q^2, r^2, s^2}
>
> {1, 1, 1}
> ```

the definition of `vf`:

```
Definition[vf]
```

> ```
> vf[a_, b_, c_] = {a^2, b^2, c^2}
> ```